# Dropdown list background color changing to white onclick in Firefox and IE - not Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, drop-down-menu

For some reason that I can't for the life of me figure out, a dropdown list that I have on the front page of my website changes its background color to white when clicked (supposed to stay brown).

I have the exact same dropdown list on my Forum page and it works fine.

I'm using this code here:

```
<select name="custom Language" style="background:#4b2d15 !important; width:225px; margin-      top:4px; display: inline-block; color:#ffffff; float:left; font-weight:normal;" value="Language you're learning...">
```

It works perfectly in Chrome if I use !important but IE and Firefox turn it white. I know this probably means something is conflicting and overriding it but I can't locate what would cause it to happen on one page and not the other.

Here's the website (it's the 'Language you're learning' list): [MezzoGuild](http://www.mezzoguild.com)

The other page that it's actually working on is: [Forum](http://www.mezzoguild.com/forum)

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Both of your links seems to be not working

Comment: @Benjamin It's weird. Reload it again and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me in Chrome,Firefox,and IE.The background color is brown for each option.

```
<select name="custom Language" style="background:#4b2d15 !important; width:225px; margin-      top:4px; display: inline-block; color:#ffffff; float:left; font-weight:normal;" value=>
<option>Option1</option>
<option>Option2</option>
</select>
```